I'm not too sure what I found but I'm thinking it might be some sort of mold
I saw something on the floor moulding that I thought at first looked like a blackened knot or a mouse but when I poked at it with drumstick it just about exploded into the mess you see in the picture. It fell on the floor and seemed like it was ultra powdery. In sort of a wisp like it was made of smoke. My wife sprayed it with a cleaner and it all wiped up fine. On the other side of this wall is a shower with tiled walls and floor. Just about where this was found is exactly where the shower head is installed. Have I got a mold problem? If the images don't come through this post, here's a dropbox link
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/6zcyi9zwimbal9xj93zgt/APGuMjhB2mUbGaoozZpWDS8?rlkey=e2xe5850z5jo3qjz4f5gdadny&dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/awhrkzdumrpsqd6po19lr/IMG_0779.jpeg?rlkey=b59egqw7nejsy1c09j70ep4bn&dl=0

No one will click on a dropbox link. Please upload an actual picture.

Even with a picture no one can be 100% positive.  It needs testing at a lab to be sure(also tells if there are health concerns).  Is there a room under there where you can open up a ceiling or use a small inspection camera placed in a small hole in the wall.

From your description you had a mushroom that exploded.
Mushrooms only grow where it is damp, so you have that condition.
Logic says to look in the wall by that "organism". You probably have a leak.
